# With @electron-forge/maker-squirrel, how do I print the path of the generated installer, so that I can set a variable in an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, electron-forge, squirrel.windows

I am setting up an Azure DevOps Pipeline for an electron-forge project on windows.

I have a [Squirrel.Windows](https://www.electronforge.io/config/makers/squirrel.windows) maker which creates the installer:

```
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "MyApplication",
          }
        }
      ]
```

I want my pipeline to pick up this path, so I can use it in e.g. a [PublishPipelineArtifact@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-artifacts) task.

I figure I can do this by using an azure [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable) to print something like

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=squirrel;isoutput=true]${INSTALLER_FULL_PATH}
```

How can I get squirrel to print out that string to stdout? Is there a better approach to this problem with Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is a hack which still hardcodes some things like the output path, but I think it should work for the most part:

```yaml
steps:
  - powershell: |
     $ci_package_json = Get-Content .\package.json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
     Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=squirrelOutput]$(pwd)\out\make\squirrel.windows\x64\$($ci_package_json.productName)-$($ci_package_json.version) Setup.exe"
  - script: echo $(squirrelOutput)
```

Would love a more robust solution.